# How to disable Align to Pixel Grid in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, pixel

When I create a new document, this option is available, but how to disable it, when the document is already created?

1. I can select shapes and disable it via the transform panel but not for newly created shapes.
2. When selecting symbol this option is greyed out, Illustrator realigns the paths anyway.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. In the top right corner fly out menu of the transform panel, you can select or deselect "Align New Objects To Pixel Grid" globally for all future objects/paths (see below image)
2. For each already created path/object use the checkbox in the transform panel itself
3. The paths within the symbol might be set to "Align To Pixel Grid". Disabling it for the specific paths might be ignored anyway, so it's necessary to dispatch the shape from the symbol, disable the align option and recreate the symbol. Illustrator bugginess FTW.

[image: transform panel]

Comment: can I do this since the document is already created? Or should I start over new document?
Also where in the preferences this can be disabled?

Comment: @Vladyn yes, as I wrote already: in the transform panel, disable "Align To Pixel Grid" globally for all future objects/paths in the fly out menu (http://d.pr/i/QFMH) but you need to disable it for each already created object/path individually in the panel itself.

Comment: This menu item appears to be gone in the latest Illustrator CC.

Answer (score 5):

you're probably best to do this when setting up a new document in the document set up dialogue box. i think you can also turn it off in the preferences which would be a good idea because in my experience it does nothing but cause trouble!

Comment: Sure but the question aims specifically at how to disable it when the document is already created.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... using pathfinder and shapes got distorted even when previously expanded.

Solved the problem by:

1. Creating a new document
2. On the first document setup panel, click **"Advanced"**
3. Then unclick the **"align new objects to pixel grid"** box.

Works perfect, and Illustrator is back.

cheers