# Pixel Grid issues and aligning anchors in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, grids, pixel

I cannot get my anchors to align properly, whether it's a new document or an existing one.

[image: Alignment example]

[Exact same issue as this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/how-to-disable-align-to-pixel-grid-in-illustrator), only now with CC, there doesn't seem to be a way to "uncheck align to pixel grid" and Adobe has no fix for this issue in their "Help" and I couldn't find anything (current) on their forums. 
Is there a different label for it, or has this feature been removed completely?

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question after a little more searching and experimentation. Figures I'd spend three hours looking for this, ask about it here, then find it immediately after.

You need to make sure the **"Align art to pixel grid on creation and transformation" button is "unchecked"** (unchecked in my version of CC means 'not surrounded in a darker shade of gray'). 
The worst part about this button is that there is no specific window where you can find it. It's not in transformation, pathfinder, or any other window that might make sense.

This button is in the top-right corner of the main Illustrator window. underneath the "Search Adobe Stock" search bar. See picture:

[image: "Align art to pixel grid on creation and transformation" Button]

It's the button that looks like 3 little blocks and a magnet.

---

*If the button is not there*, which it wasn't for me, you need to *reset your panel layout*.

**Method 1** (the one I used):
Click on the panel layout button, again top-right of the main Illustrator window, and click "Essentials". Please note that depending on your current panel layout this button will say the name of your layout with a dropdown ("Essentials" by default, I think) or it will be an icon. If the button is still not there, go back to the same button and click "Reset Essentials".

**Method 2** (untested, please confirm!):
Click in menu: Window > Workspace > Essentials
If the "Align art to pixel grid on creation and transformation" button is still not there, click the panel layout button, now in the top-right corner (labeled "Essentials" with a dropdown) and then click "Reset Essentials".

On a side note, I find this is extremely annoying since I liked my custom layout.
Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: You can save your layout with a different name before you reset it. Anyway if you want to have a problem free life never enable the align to pixel grid option for any reason (its on for certain templates). Use a normal grid instead it does not have problems.

Comment: “never enable the align to pixel grid option for any reason” is good advice. I agree with @joojaa, snap to grid is a better choice for pixel snapped artwork than using snap to pixels.